# Django modify bridge table

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in my django application, event/user, that have a many-to-many relationship.

Event can have many attendees(user).
User can attend many events.

Django automatically made a bridge table for for this relationship.

My question is how can I add new fields to this table using migrations as there is not a model for this Bridge table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by creating a "through" table and adding the fields on it. Check out the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/models/

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It's the most django way of extending the intermediary table.

Answer (score 1):

This bridge table is called association table. Imo it is bad practice to edit this table that way. Connecting models by many to many field suggest that there is no model between. If your association table is supposed to represent additional data then you should create new model

```
class NewModel(models.Model):
    attender = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=False)
    # additional fileds
```

and remove many to many relationship from event

Comment: I will add a new model as u suggested. In this case i want to have a date to represent when the user attended the event. Also how can remove the existing association table?

Comment: Remove many to many relationship, run makemigrations and migrate. Django will notice changes and will remove association table